# taxonomy_radio is not showing anything in the front-end in cmb2

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am building a website in where I want to show the tag selected from the custom fields (*mainly from radio button*). I have setup the cmb2 as like below the codes..

```
add_action('cmb2_admin_init', 'custom_metaboxes');
function custom_metaboxes() {
$metabox = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'object_types' => array( 'post'), //for the post
    'title'        => 'Additional Fields',
    'id'           => 'additional'
    )
 );
 // showing in the admin panel
$metabox -> add_field( array(
    'name' => 'Taxonomy List',
    'desc' => 'This get the list of taxonomy',
    'id'   => 'taxonomy_list',
    'type' => 'taxonomy_radio',
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'default'  => 'ami'
  )
 );
}
```

Ok, that is working in the post section. My tags are shown in the radio buttons, That's working. But when I tried to show the the selected tag in the front-end using

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'taxonomy_list', true )// returns nothing
```

nothing is echoing. Then tried `var_dump` function  it returns `string(0) ""`. What are the problems are working behind the scene.

Anyone please find out what the problems are.

Comment: Are you sure in Post meta table, key is `taxonomy_list` ? if yes, search in Database if post meta value exists for given post id.

Comment: I did not get any meta key `taxonomy_list` in the post meta table for the given post id. Now what can I do at this moment to solve this?

Comment: It means, `taxonomy_list`is not inserted into database, please check code where its inserted.

Comment: How do I know where the problem is. I have only these codes. Why the meta key is not inserted?

Comment: Any one please help me out.. I am stacked with it.

Comment: I have faced the same problem

Comment: Do you have any solution of this now?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by using cmb2-2.0.2 version. And here is the code:

```html
<?php

add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'yourprefix_register_demo_metabox' );

function yourprefix_register_demo_metabox() {

 $prefix = '_yourprefix_demo_';

 $cmb_demo = new_cmb2_box( array(
  'id'            => $prefix . 'additional',
  'title'         => 'Additional Fields',
  'object_types'  => array('page')
 ) );

 $cmb_demo->add_field( array(
  'name'       => 'Taxonomy List',
  'desc'       => 'This get the list of taxonomy',
  'id'         => $prefix . 'taxonomy_list',
  'type'       => 'taxonomy_radio',
  'taxonomy'       => 'post_tag'
 ) );
}

?>
```

And in frontend you need to write:

```html
<?php

$prefix = '_yourprefix_demo_';
echo get_tag(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $prefix.'taxonomy_list', true)[0])->name;
?>
```